# Адаптивная плитка каталога

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, float

Как сделать фиксированную ширину и высоту для блоков, например 250х250, так чтобы при этом левый блок был прижат к левому краю, а правый к правому как в примере, а центральные имели равномерные отступы.  Без использования flex.

```css
.product-wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 450px) {
  .product-wrapper {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .product-wrapper {
    width: 33.333%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .product-wrapper {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
.product {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #b5e9a7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #474747;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 300px;
}
.products {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 -20px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="products clearfix">
  <li class="product-wrapper">
    <a href="" class="product"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="product-wrapper">
    <a href="" class="product"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="product-wrapper">
    <a href="" class="product"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="product-wrapper">
    <a href="" class="product"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="product-wrapper">
    <a href="" class="product"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="product-wrapper">
    <a href="" class="product"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="product-wrapper">
    <a href="" class="product"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="product-wrapper">
    <a href="" class="product"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: А в чем проблема-то? Исходя из вопроса, ваш пример по ссылке работает как нужно.

Comment: Ну сейчас я вот заметил что к правому краю не прижимается, отрицательный margin не сработал, хотя только что проверял.
Проблема в том, что ширина и высота должны быть не в процентах, а пикселях с тем же эффектом.

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос: дайте всем `li` одинаковый `margin` (убрав его у `a`), затем первому уберите слева `margin`, а последнему справа

Comment: В таком случае у меня не получится сделать 3 блока в один ряд ни с относительной шириной ни с фиксированной

Answer (score 2):

Знаю только один способ чего-то подобного без flex'ов, но у него есть существенный минус - требуется кратность, иначе блоки разъезжаются в последней строке. Но может пригодится, не вам, так ещё кому-то:

```css
.products-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.products {
  display: block;
  list-style:none;
  margin: -10px;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 0;
}

.products:before,
.products:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}

.product-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.product {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #b5e9a7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #474747;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 270px;
  height: 270px;
}
```

```html
<div class="products-container">
  <ul class="products">
    <li class="product-wrapper">
      <a href="" class="product"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="product-wrapper">
      <a href="" class="product"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="product-wrapper">
      <a href="" class="product"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="product-wrapper">
      <a href="" class="product"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="product-wrapper">
      <a href="" class="product"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="product-wrapper">
      <a href="" class="product"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="product-wrapper">
      <a href="" class="product"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="product-wrapper">
      <a href="" class="product"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Такой подобный вариант уже был испробован и как раз из за этого минуса не был принят) Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Без флексов )). И в последующих рядах блоки повторяют конфигурацию предыдущего ряда (не разъезжаются)

```css
.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 270px);
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.item{
  width:270px;
  height: 270px;
  border: 1px solid #cda;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```